# Creating problem-sets with answers in Latex

Tags: latex

I want to typeset Mathematical problem-sets in Latex. My requirements are as follows:

When I type them in, I want the questions and the answers to be next to each other in the source-code so that fixing errors, etc. can be done easily.

*However*, when the document is typeset, I want the answers to appear in a separate "Answers" section just the way they do in textbooks.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are looking for *deferred printing*. There are packages that can handle this problem, for instance [`exercise`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/). This does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Define a 'question' and a 'solution' environment in your `questions.tex` file (say). Include `questions.tex` twice. The first time, include questions only. The second time, include solutions only.

```
\usepackage{version}

% Include questions but not solutions:
\includeversion{question}\excludeversion{solution}

% Include solutions but not questions:
%\excludeversion{question}\includeversion{solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item  % Shared question marker.
\begin{question}
Question goes here.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
solution goes here
\end{solution}
```

Comment: @Pieter's answer is better, but I leave this here for reference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a lot of code to do this. There are two approaches. One is you can have a function that keeps adding the answers to a variable that just gets bigger and bigger. The second is you can have function that writes to a file and then, later, reads the file into your document. Frankly, the variable method is easier, even though it seems grosser.