# typeset problem/solution pair (example) in latex

Tags: latex, typesetting

I'd like to know if there is a way in latex to show the following:

```
Example 1: problem statement here
Solution: solution here
```

and wrap that in a box so that it will be noticeable.

Seems like a common enough problem that there should be ready made solutions

If there are any suggestions it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the [`exercise`](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf) package. For more information, look at the manual or [a previous topic on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924313/creating-problem-sets-with-answers-in-latex/2924374). A (modified) example from the manual:

```
\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise Discuss\ldots
  \Answer $\ldots$
\end{ExerciseList}
```